# Migrating to SCCM from WSUS-only updates. Keep existing approvals?

Tags: windows-update, wsus, sccm

I've got a small 1-site SCCM 2007 deployment and I'm just getting to grips with pushing out Windows Updates to SCCM clients using it. I've previously managed updates by manually approving from WSUS and then installing manually across the client estate. Obviously, SCCM will allow me to do this better.

The question I have is what to do with the existing set of approvals that WSUS has. There's a large number of updates that are marked as 'approved' and therefore have content downloaded to WSUS's content directory.

In SCCM, I'm planning on adding all the updates I want deployed to a specific update deployment package, which appears to mean downloading all these updates again to a network share, and then copying them over to a distribution point.

Should I just ignore the fact that WSUS has already downloaded some of these updates, and therefore write off the disk space taken up by them, or is there a better way I can 'clear out' WSUS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible, but a little cumbersome.

Fortunately, this blog post provides a step-by-step walkthrough of how it can be accomplished:
http://syscenterstuff.blogspot.com/2010/12/sccm-migrating-from-wsus-to-sccm.html